# Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms.play-service:8.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have a problem with my app.
This error is shown after updated SDK success.

[image: Android Studio output]

Comment: You need to include relevant source code in your question itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 No,i don't click Install Repository and sync project.

Comment: Do you need **all** the play services? You should just [pick the dependencies you need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use version 8.4.0

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

[Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: please,complete the answer, if you use play-service 8.4.0 you need create file configuration in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your dependency. Open your `build.gradle` and change:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms.play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

The difference being the `:` instead of `.` between `gms` and `play-services`.

Also you should use the latest version : 8.4.0